# How to remove "Extended Demographics"?

Tags: custom-fields, extension, sql, civihr

Years ago we tried out CiviHR and it added something which looks like a set of custom fields, called "Extended Demographics". We uninstalled the extension but this did not go away. I can't find anywhere in Civi settings how to disable or remove it. I've ignored it till now but we are about to give a lot more people access to Civi and it will confuse people having irrelevant (and very personal!) fiends on there.

I suspect it was a bug in CiviHR that caused it to be left behind. If I want to remove it from the database using MySQL (which I am very familiar with) then is there anything I need to know so I don't break anything? We have backups, but the less blindly I can bash at the live site the better.

Obvs if there is a setting I've missed that would be much better

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest would be if you can find it in the CiviCRM custom groups? Using Administer/Customize Data and Screens/Custom Fields. If that does not work, check the table civicrm_custom_group. You will probably see an entry there with the column name 'is_reserved' having the value 1. 
If that is the case, change the value for 'is_reserved' to 0 and check if you can see the custom group in the Administer menu now?

This would be the best way as you would delete all that you want to delete. If that fails, shout again?

Comment: Perfect, thanks - setting is_reserved to 0 did the trick.